# how to select ul to insert a li via jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm doing some stuffs in front-end using jquery. I have following elements in my html

```
        <div id="filtering" class="top-buffer">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <ul class="event-list" id="appending">
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                 </div>
             </div>                            
        </div> 
    <script>
    function  getQuoteRow(value){
        $str='';
        $str+=   '<li>';
        $str+=       '<time datetime=""><span class="month">'+value.category_name+'</span></time>';
        $str+=           '<div class="info" style="background-color:#'+value.bg_color_picker+'">';
        $str+=           ' <h3 class="title" >';
        $str+=               value.quote.replace(/\\/g, "");
        $str+=           '</div>';
        $str+=           '<div class="social"><ul>';
        $str+=               '<li class="pencil" style="width:33%;"><a href="/admin/viewQuotes?edit=ok&id='+value.quote_id+'" class="icon-pencil"><span class="fa fa-pencil"></span></a></li>';
        $str+=               '<li class="trash" style="width:33%;"><a href="/admin/viewQuotes?delete=ok&id='+value.quote_id+'" onclick="return delConfirm()" class="icon-trash"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></a></li>';
        $str+=               '<li class="facebook" style="width:33%;"><a href="#facebook"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span></a></li>';
        $str+=               '<li class="twitter" style="width:34%;"><a href="#twitter"><span class="fa fa-twitter"></span></a></li>';
        $str+=           '</ul></div>';
        $str+=     '</li>';
        return $str;

    }
    </script>
```

Here how to select the  in jquery to append a row?
I used the following selectors it's not worked those are

```
$("#filtering ul").append(getQuoteRow(value));
$("#appending").append(getQuoteRow(value));
```

But while i call **$("#filtering").append(getQuoteRow(value));** it's appending under div tag..

how to select the ul??

Comment: We don't know what `getQuoterow()` is

Comment: use `$('#appending')` to select `ul`

Comment: Instead of using $("#filtering").append(getQuoteRow(value));, Use 

$("#appending").append(getQuoteRow(value));

Comment: getQuoterow() is creating set of elements using value parameter and retrn as a string of those elements

Comment: $("#appending").append(getQuoteRow(value)); i tried but it's not worked

Comment: alert(getQuoteRow(value)); what is the output of this?

Comment: yah it'gives the li elements

Answer (score 2):

You can use like this

```
$("#appending").append(getQuoteRow(value))
```

reference example

```
$("#appending").append("<li>test</li>")
```

Answer (score 0):

> *while i call $("#filtering").append(getQuoteRow(value)); it's appending under div tag..*

That is because div have id `filtering` and `#filtering` will select element with id `filtering`. You have id for ul element as well,i.e. `appending`. You can use:

```
$("#appending").append(getQuoteRow(value));
```

Answer (score 0):

in your function your H3 tag is opened but not closed

```
$str+= ' <h3 class="title" >';
```

need somewhere like

```
$str+= '</h3>';
```